# SQL to select distinct values from one column where another column has varying values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a huge amount of data. To explain the issue, consider this ultra-minimal set of data:

```
id     col1    col2
-------------------
1      ab      12
2      ab      12
3      ab      12
4      cd      34
5      cd      43
6      ef      34
7      ef      56
8      ef      34
```

What I need is to select all distinct values in `col1` where there is more than one value in `col2`. So the results from the above would be something like this:

```
col1
----
cd
ef
```

Or even better, a row for each unique corresponding value in `col2`:

```
col1    col2
------------
ab      12
cd      34
cd      43
ef      34
ef      56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `group by` and `having`:

```
select col2
from t
group by col2
having min(col2) <> max(col2);
```

If you just want the distinct values, use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct col1, col2
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks! `group by` and `having` are two parts of SQL I'm not that familiar with, but it makes complete sense now.

Answer (score 1):

First one, return col1 values having at least two different col2 values:

```
select col1 from
tablename
group by col1
having count(distinct col2) >= 2
```

Second, return col1 with col2, when col1 has at least two different col2 values:

```
select * from tablename
where col1 in (
    select col1 from
    tablename
    group by col1
    having count(distinct col2) >= 2)
```